# Displaying % in Batch (Windows 10 Command Prompt)

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch program that has a loading screen, because it has a lot of files to load,  anyway, I was trying to get it to display:

```
0%
```

after runing the program, it only displayed:

```
0
```

Any advice or solutions would help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape this special character by adding `%`

```bat
@echo off
echo 0%%
pause>nul
```

for more info about escaping characters take a look at this link : **[Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

Answer (score 0):

You shall display `%` in console by giving `%%` in your batch program.

Comment: In the console you wouldn't need to double the percent sign, just in a batch.

Comment: @LotPings. Yes, we have to give  `%%` in batch to display `%` in console.